# jQuery Show/hide inputs based on multiple select options

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a drop-down which allows multiple product selection and based on the products selected I want to show inputs for products extra and add a required attribute to those inputs.

```js
var products = $('#products').select2({
    tags: true
});

products.on('change', function() {
  var ids = products.val();
  setExtras(ids);
});

function setExtras(ids) {
  $.each(ids, function(index, id) {
    $('#extras .form-group').each(function() {
      if ($(this).hasClass('extra_' + id)) {
        $(this).show('fade').find('input').prop('required', true);
      } else {
        $(this).hide('fade').find('input').prop('required', false);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">

  <label for="products">Products</label>
  <select multiple="" class="form-control select2" name="products[]" id="products">
    <option value="1">Product One</option>
    <option value="2">Product Two</option>
  </select>
  <span class="help-block">Please select your product</span>

</div>

<div id="extras">

  <div style="display: none;" class="form-group extra_1">
    <label for="1_1">
      Product One(Message)
      </label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="1_1" name="extras[1][1]" placeholder="Your message here">
  </div>

  <div style="display: none;" class="form-group extra_2">
    <label for="2_2">
      Product Two(Message)
      </label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="2_2" name="extras[2][2]" placeholder="Your message here">
  </div>

  <div style="display: none;" class="form-group extra_2">
    <label for="2_3">
      Product Two(Tag Line)
      </label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="2_3" name="extras[2][3]" placeholder="Your tag line here">
  </div>

</div>
```

My current JS code only shows inputs for last selected product, please help me out to fix that.

**P.S.** The product extras will be variable, some products has one or more extra and some will have none.

Comment: Where is the select2 function?

Comment: Just using Select2 plugin (https://select2.org/) to style the select input and to add tag behavior to it.

Comment: Ok! I dont fully understand what you're trying to do - do you want the input to stay put even if you select another option?

Comment: Sorry if you could not understand it properly. Actually what I want is if the user selects Product One and Product Two then I want to show him/her the extra inputs labeled as: Product One(Message), Product Two(Message), Product Two(Tag Line) and if the selected product is Product One then the extra inputs labeled as: Product One(Message),

Comment: Ok, so if both one and two are selected you want to show all three?

Comment: yes, now you understood correctly. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try change code of function `setExtras`

```
function setExtras(ids) {
   $('#extras .form-group').each(function () {
      $(this).hide('fade').find('input').prop('required', false);
    });
   $.each(ids, function (index, id) {
    $('#extras .form-group').each(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('extra_' + id)) {
            $(this).show('fade').find('input').prop('required', true);
        } 
    });
   });
}
```

This is a demo link: https://codepen.io/phuongnm153/pen/PvwoZg